# Object Reference not set to the instance of an Object in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I have dataaccass  in my solution. I am using this dataaccess to  retrieve data. and i  am calling the function of the dataaccess part from my aspx.cs page my code sample as follows:

```
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = objYPCategoryMasterDataAccess.GetAllSubCategory(CategoryID);
```

when i build it goes well but when i debug it it throws an exception as  object reference not set to the instance of the object. help me please.

with Regard

Comment: @WouterDeKort is likely correct, but if you share your code in it's entirety, you may get a more exact answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Type error occurs when your `Object` Is null. You Can set It By

```
  objYPCategoryMasterDataAccess= new YPCategoryMasterDataAccess();
```

Try this It may help you

Answer (score 3):

This error tells you that you are calling an object on a method that has no value. In your code, this probably means that `objYPCategoryMasterDataAccess` is `null`. You can set a breakpoint in your code and then debug it to inspect the value at runtime.